# Action Listener in PHP/Mysql, whenever any record inserted into table?

Tags: php, mysql

Is their any method/way that we come to know, any change occurs in desired table?

I have implemented one solution that it checks in db every 30 sec, that is if any change occur in chats table then refresh my chats listing. it waists lot of performance and slow down the site.

Is their any way that our action listener only calls whenever any row is inserted in table?

Any idea?

Comment: Look for mysql Triggers. Or alternatively you can use socket listener some kind of socket.io with nodejs

Comment: @LoVeSmItH Is any alternative in php?

Comment: You can use socket. Forexample you can use socket.io with nodejs. but again this will be much more complex. The better way is using Triggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create table with notifications (which will always contains just unread messages for last 2 hours or so) and then create [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) [[syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)] that will create new notification each time change occurs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_notification AFTER INSERT ON chats
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO notifications (...) VALUES( NEW.col1, NEW.col2)...
```

Then you'll end up with much smaller (and faster) database table.

There are some alternatives like writing a socket server but I think it would be less resource effective than pooling database plus I have a bad experience running php scripts for a long time.

Comment: I realized this is not what he wanted, he want to avoid querying database much to often to fetch new chats. So I think like you and I suggested trigger will not help him?

Comment: @LoVeSmItH polling data from one dedicated table which has just 10-1000 records seems to be much better way to me than getting some summarized data from large table (like `MAX(date) ... WHERE forumId = ... GROUP BY ...`

Comment: I have thought that too, thats why I have +1 ed your solution. But reading his question. I just realized he doesnt want that... last part of his question `Is their any way that our action listener only calls whenever any row is inserted in table?`

Comment: @LoVeSmItH Exactly I need it, just our refresh list calls only if new record is inserted in chats table!

Comment: @LoVeSmItH sadly I think this is the most resource effective and most reliable way how to do this in php... Only another thing I can think of in this context is php socket server and this isn't the way to go :-/

Answer (score 2):

well in your scenario you need a listener, which tracks the moment the new row of chat is inserted to the database.

It will be easier if you emit chat message to the users before you insert it into the database.

You can use socket. you can either use nodejs+socket.io to perform this. Here is bit about that

[socket.io and node.js to send message to particular client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629497/socket-io-and-node-js-to-send-message-to-particular-client)

You can also look this  article

https://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0

Comment: our application is serviced based, either third parties can also insert the messages in our db, so I think socket might be not best solution?