# Load data, only when someone submit new message

Tags: php, ajax, database

So I created really simple chatbox in php. It works very good, but I had to set up script that is nonstop loading data from database to the chat window (not probably the most efficient way, that's why I am asking):

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#chatbox').html('Loading...');
    $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){loop()}, 0);
    function loop(){
     $('#chatbox').load('/chatbox.php');
    }

}); 
    </script>
```

And in chatbox.php:

```
include '/classes/class.chatbox.php';
$chat = new Chat();
$chatboxMsg = $chat->getNewMessages();
echo $chatboxMsg;
```

But this isn't the problem. My question is, how can I load the data (=refresh chat) for ALL users that have opened chat window,  only when someone post new message (=insert new row to the db), without running script that is checking something every second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need events generated by server.

The fastest and recommended solutions for that are based on:

```
Node.js
```

More possibilities using:

- AJAX long polling
- HTML5 Server Sent Events
- HTML5 Websockets
- Comet

Attached links and samples:

- [socket.io and node.js to send message to particular client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629497/socket-io-and-node-js-to-send-message-to-particular-client)
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax1/index.html

Comment: This looks promising.. but it will probably take some time because I have never heard about these things (except Node.js, but I don't use it too). Anyway, thanks for suggestions, I hope I'll find solutions there.

Comment: @user3560463: I have updated my answer.. Yes, this is gonna take some time, but i would prefer going for node based solution, it is really sexy ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need listeners. Here is how you can implement them the best way: [PHP Event-Listener best-practice implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471183/php-event-listener-best-practice-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Check the socket.io. You will definitely find it to be the easiest way of doing it. When a new message arrises you can braodcast the message . Here are some of the references that you can use

- http://tamas.io/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-1/
- [socket.io and node.js to send message to particular client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629497/socket-io-and-node-js-to-send-message-to-particular-client)

Hope it helps